# Alternative for img:[alt]hover:after

Tags: css

I'm a novice coder. I am using a WordPress template (Semplice) to help set up my new website.

The behavior I want is to hover over an image, and display customized text. I believe I could do this with a tooltip or with HTML5 pseudo selectors.

I can add custom CSS to my theme, as well as JavaScript. I can also add custom classes to images I upload. So I thought my approach in the CSS would be:

```
.this-is-a-custom-class img[alt]:hover:after {
  content: attr(alt);
  position: absolute;
  top:-100%;
  left:0%;
}
```

But as I dig around it looks like those pseudo selectors don't work for images?

Can anybody suggest a way around this, given that I am limited to adding my own custom CSS, JavaScript, and custom classes for my images?

Comment: What is the `alt` stuff in your code? I mean, you have it written differently between your title and your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple solution:

```js
$(function() {
  //get all images at detach them from the document; you can change this class name
  var allImages = $('.image-class').detach();


  //create the mark up pattern
  allImages = createMarkup(allImages);

  //add new mark up back to the document
  allImages.each(function(index, element) {
    $('.container').append(element);
  })


  function createMarkup(images) {
    var container = [];

    images.each(function(index, element) {
      var imageContainer = $('<div class="img-container"></div>');
      var imageText = $('<p class="img-container__text"></p>')

      imageText.text($(element).attr('alt'));

      imageContainer.append(element, imageText);

      container.push(imageContainer);
    });

    return $(container);
  }
});
```

```css
.img-container {
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  margin: 100px auto;
}

.img-container__text {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: -100px;
  left: 0;
}

.img-container__img {
  width: 100%;
}

.img-container:hover>.img-container__text {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <img class="image-class" src="https://www.mozilla.org/media/img/home/dino.d3d01561e288.svg" alt="Hello">
</div>
```

It works by changing the mark up dynamically with jQuery when the page loads and setting a hover state on a `div` that is the parent of the image. In the same containing `div` element I include a child element for the text you want to show when the image is hovered over, with a display property of none.

When the container is hovered over, the element that holds the text gets a display value of block.

The way you wish to do it won't work because images are replaced elements and ::before and ::after pseudo elements only work with non-replaced elements

Per the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter):

> The pseudo-elements generated by ::before and ::after are contained by
>   the element's formatting box, and thus don't apply to replaced
>   elements such as , or to 
>  elements.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Here's my followup question: I can't edit my HTML to set up the container the way you have it. I can only add CSS and Javascript to my existing code. So I cannot set up a div that holds the image, and I cannot add text (like a P) inside the image container div.

The images I upload *can* have custom classes. They have alt and caption fields, which I can customize too.

I know I’m a new coder, so am I missing something obvious and even in my constrained setup, there *is* some way for me to update the HTML with a spot for that custom text?

Comment: @TS Is it possible for you to add javascript to the element that contains the images?

Comment: I can add JavaScript globally via the CMS I'm using. Not sure if I can make it more specific than that. I can also manually download and edit any of the files that make up the site - it's Wordpress - if it comes to that.

Comment: Here is the setup of the image that I want to target and show info from: <a class="semplice-lightbox">

<img class="is-content lightbox-item" src="https://my-site-here.nfshost.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/2018-overview-001-1.jpg" width="1067" height="1600" alt="Alt Text” caption="Custom caption Text” data-width="original" data-scaling="no" data-photoswipe-index="0">

</a>

Comment: @TS Okay so you need to add a javascript function that finds all the images that you want to have the hover state and essentially create the mark up pattern that I have in my answer for each image. Are you using jQuery on your site?

Comment: yes, it's jQuery. Thank you so much for the thoughts.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help, Daniel. I am grateful you took the time. I'll ask if I have more questions.

Comment: @TS No problem! If my solution worked please do accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxqadW : Does this answer your question ? If not, tell me

If you have problems understanding the code, don't hesitate asking me questions.

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
  <img id="image" src= "https://picsum.photos/200/300"/>
  <div id="information">
    Hello there
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
#container{
  width:200px;
  position:relative;
}

#image{
  max-width:100%;
}

#information{
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  display:none;
}
```

JS :

```
document.getElementById("image").onmouseover=function(){
  document.getElementById("information").style.display="inline";
}

document.getElementById("image").onmouseleave=function(){
  document.getElementById("information").style.display="none";
}
```